# What happened to US-CERT Weekly Vulnerability Bulletins?

Tags: vulnerability

What happened to US-CERT weekly bulletins about new vulnerabilities? It was one of my sources to get updates about new vulnerabilities and I received nothing since January 25.

On the website, also nothing since January, 25.

https://www.us-cert.gov/ncas/bulletins

Anyone know the reason?

Will it be continued?

Comment: I feel like this is something you should info@us-cert.gov about.

Comment: @RoraΖ Yurp.  `We are resolving issues affecting our weekly security bulletins, but hope to resume posting them soon.`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[The February 1st report seems to be restricted access](https://www.us-cert.gov/ncas/bulletins/SB16-039), though I can't say for what reason.

The February 8th and 15th reports don't seem to exist, or at least not at the urls at which they would be expected.

Edit/Update:

[image]

They are apparently having unspecified issues which are affecting their weekly security bulletins in unspecified ways, but are in an unspecified process of applying unspecified resolutions to these unspecified issues, and they hope that they will be able to resume posting their security bulletins at an unspecified time in the near future.